# cos(2i) into exponential form

Tags: complex-numbers

I need to put cos(2i) into exponential form. 
So far I have $$\frac {e^{i(2i)}+e^{-i(2i)}} {2} $$

$$\frac {e^{-2}+e^{2}} {2}$$

I am not sure if this is correct or where to go from here

Comment: Equals $\cosh 2$  looks fine.

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_functions

Comment: It is correct.   And we define the hyperbolic function $\cosh(x)$ as $$\cosh(x)=\frac12(e^x+e^{-x})$$

Comment: Furthermore, how would I convert this into cartesian form?

Comment: well it is already, since it's a real number.

Comment: Remember the general identity $\cos(ix)=\cosh(x)$